# Methods on ArrayLists

Tags: java

I am just working on my knowledge of `ArrayLists` and have a question.

I have 4 classes, a person superclass, employee subclass, pupil subclass and a manager subclass of employee.

What I don't understand is how I can use the method `m.setBonus` on the people `ArrayList`. I know I can split the objects into separate arrays but I'm not sure if that is the answer.

I am currently getting an error on the `Manager m : manager` part because there is no reference for manager I assume.

I currently have this code in my test class

```
public static void main(String[] args){

ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

people.add(new Employee("Tom", 4000, 1990, 3, 10));
people.add(new Pupil("Dick", "Comp Sci"));
people.add(new Employee("Harry", 4000, 1990, 3, 10));
people.add(new Manager ("Dan", 5000, 1990, 10, 1));

for (Manager m : manager)
{
    m.setBonus(5000);
}

for (Person p : people){

    System.out.println(p.getDetails());
}

}

}
```

I am sorry if this is a really simple thing. I just can't find anything on the net.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manager arrayList does not exist, instead do the check in your existing Person loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

    people.add(new Employee("Tom", 4000, 1990, 3, 10));
    people.add(new Pupil("Dick", "Comp Sci"));
    people.add(new Employee("Harry", 4000, 1990, 3, 10));
    people.add(new Manager ("Dan", 5000, 1990, 10, 1));

    // manager arrayList does not exist
    //for (Manager m : manager)
    //{
    //  m.setBonus(5000);
    //}


    for (Person p : people){
        //Do this instead
        if (p instanceof Manager) {
            ((Manager) p).setBonus(5000);
        }

        System.out.println(p.getDetails());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You never declare a list of managers called `manager` so it has no idea what to do with it.

You'll need to do something like this:

```
for (Person p : people)
{
    if (p instanceof Manager) {
        ((Manager)p).setBonus(5000);
    }
}
```

This will check the class of p to confirm if it is subclass Manager or not.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will go read the instanceof section of the book! :)

Comment: You may need to cast that reference to a `Manager` instance - I doubt `Pupil`s are getting bonuses.

Comment: That is a solution, and perhaps the only solution for the way the original poster has set up the problem, but whenever I see large use of instanceof, I worry that the overall design may be broken, and that there may be a better way of solving the underlying problem.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I completely agree. I've been using Java for about 7 years or so now and I can't think of a single program off the top of my head where I used `instanceof`. I'm pretty sure I only learned of it a year ago or so.